Title: Issues with Python Chatbot App Using Toga and BeeWare for Android
I have a Python codebase, and I’m developing an Android application using the Toga and BeeWare libraries. The app is a chatbot. When I click on the chat input field, type a topic, and send the message, the code is supposed to fetch a response from a JSON file and display it to the user.
However, upon clicking the "Send Message" button, the app throws various errors, such as "not assigned" and other bugs. Despite using ChatGPT for corrections, the issues persist. I need help resolving these bugs.
Funções
class EasyEnglishHelp(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
         def conversa(window_twu, widget):
            box_principal_conversa = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,
                                                         alignment=CENTER,
                                                         flex=1,
                                                         background_color=BEIGE))

            espaco_one = toga.Box(style=Pack(alignment=CENTER,
                                             flex=1))

            entrada_linha = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,
                                                alignment=CENTER,
                                                padding=100,
                                                background_color=BEIGE))

            entrada_linha_dois = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,
                                                     alignment=CENTER,
                                                     padding=100,
                                                     background_color=BEIGE))

            box_pe = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,
                                         width=200,
                                         height=200,
                                         alignment=CENTER,
                                         background_color=BEIGE,
                                         padding=10))

            botao_home_one = toga.Button(icon=toga.Icon("resources/cardapio1.png"),
                                         style=Pack(width=90,
                                                    height=80,
                                                    alignment=CENTER,
                                                    background_color=BEIGE),
                                         on_press=partial(home, self.main_window))

            bottom_container_one = toga.Box(
                children=[botao_home_one],
                style=Pack(direction=ROW,
                           alignment=CENTER,
                           padding=(10, 20)))

            # caixa de entrada de mensagem
            self.usuario_input = toga.TextInput(placeholder="Digite sua mensagem", style=Pack(color=BLACK,
                                                                                         flex=1))
            

            # Area para exibir mensagens
            self.mostra_mensagem_te = toga.MultilineTextInput(readonly=True, style=Pack(color=BLACK,
                                                                                     flex=1))

            # botão de enviar
            self.bot_enviar = toga.Button("Enviar", on_press=self.mensage, style=Pack(width=100))

            box_principal_conversa.add(espaco_one)
            box_principal_conversa.add(entrada_linha_dois)
            box_principal_conversa.add(entrada_linha)
            box_principal_conversa.add(box_pe)

            entrada_linha_dois.add(self.mostra_mensagem_te)
            entrada_linha.add(self.usuario_input)
            entrada_linha.add(self.bot_enviar)

            box_pe.add(bottom_container_one)

            window_twu.content = box_principal_conversa


    def mensage(self, widget):
        user_message = self.usuario_input().value.strip()
        if user_message:
            # Adicionar mensagem do usuário ao chat
            self.mostra_mensagem_te().value += f'Você: {user_message}\n'

            # Resposta do bot
            bot_response = self.resposta(user_message)
            self.mostra_mensagem_te().value += f'Bot: {bot_response}\n'

            # Limpar o campo de entrada
            self.usuario_input().value = ''

    def resposta(self, widget):
        try:
            # Caminho completo para o arquivo JSON
            json_path = os.path.join(self.paths.app, "resources/Dicionário_frases.json")
            with open(json_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as arquivo:
                frases = json.load(arquivo)
                # Buscar resposta correspondente
            return frases.get(self.mensage.lower(), frases.get("default"))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return "Erro: Arquivo de respostas não encontrado."
        except Exception as e:
            return f"Erro ao processar a mensagem: {e}"


(From https://github.com/beeware/toga/discussions/3024)
The one thing that stands out in the code is that you're treating usuario_input and mostra_mensagen_te as functions - in mensage(), you should be using user_message = self.usuario_input.value.strip(), self.mostra_mensagem_te.value += f'Você: {user_message}\n', and self.usuario_input.value = ''.
In future, please include the complete error message when asking questions.
